# PHP sort tables with click and on another click sort reverse

Tags: php, postgresql, sorting

I want to sort my table by clicking a header of my table, I have already figured out how to do that here : [How to sort rows of HTML table that are called from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489783/how-to-sort-rows-of-html-table-that-are-called-from-mysql)

However I am wondering, is there away, that by clicking a second time on that button, the sort will go reverse and by clicking a third time back to normal, etc ?

Comment: Set a boolean GET/POST variable that will adjust the order of your query. Dynamically set the link/submit depending on the boolean value as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done like this:

```
switch($_GET['dir']){

  case "asc":
    $orderBy = " ORDER BY colName ASC"
    break;

  case "desc":
    $orderBy = " ORDER BY colName DESC"
    break;

  default:
    $orderBy = " ORDER BY colName ASC"
    break;
}

$sql = "SELECT FieldNames from MyTable" . $orderBy;
```

Then you just provide a link with a querystring changing the `dir` item each time. So your link would become:

```
<a href="myFile.php?dir=asc">Order ascending</a>
```

or

```
<a href="myFile.php?dir=desc">Order descending</a>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by sending an attribute in url `sort=asc` , `sort=desc`. And in php: `if($_GET['sort']='asc')` sort must be `desc`. Else sort must be `asc`.

www.example.com?sort=asc

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you only want to sort the table then you don't have to reload the page (which might be relatively slow) - there is options to do it client side using JavaScript, ie [SortTable by Stuart Langridge](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using DataTables, it is very handy.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to change the anchor in header using a JS link:

```
if(/* current sorting is asc */) {
  document.write("<p>Type".link("mypage.php?sort=desc") + "</p>");
}else if(/* current sorting is desc */) {
  document.write("<p>Type".link("mypage.php?sort=normal") + "</p>");
}else if(/* current sorting is normal */){
  document.write("<p>Type".link("mypage.php?sort=asc") + "</p>");
```

PHP code will remain the same as in the previous question You asked at SO.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what you want, is here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15827728/2220389

with the first click, your table will be sorted ascending, with another click - descending.