# Sort table with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

How can I sort this `foreach` loop with jQuery? I will sort on `id` but I don't now how to do that.

```
   <form id="fileForm" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="get">
       <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="grid">
            <tr>
                <th>ID:</th>
                <th>Time:</th>
                <th>Location:</th>
                <th>From IP:</th>
                <th>Title (url):</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <td>1</td>
                 <td>12:00</td>
                 <td>Utrecht</td>
                 <td>192.019.192.00</td>
                 <td>site</td>
            </tr>
       </table>
  </form>
```

Comment: Sort? If you use jQuery please show final HTML not the PHP

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to sort the array in PHP before generating the HTML? Or are you looking for some kind of "click here to sort the list" functionality?

Comment: You can't sort a PHP `foreach` loop with jQuery. You either sort it with PHP, or you use jQuery client-side to sort the table rows that were output by the PHP. (You can't really sort a loop anyway, though you can sort the array and then loop over it...)

Comment: I will that i can click on <th>ID</th> and than that the table will sort all ID's. I now it cann whit php but i down now how...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://datatables.net/ - is a client side JQuery plugin which will allow you to sort/paginate etc the final HTML that your PHP renders.

I would tend to use a server-side solution though if you have 1000s upon 1000s of rows as the time it takes to initially render the page would be very long.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>   
 <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
      <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th>Last Name</th> 
            <th>First Name</th> 
            <th>Email</th> 
            <th>Due</th> 
            <th>Web Site</th> 
        </tr> 
      </thead> 
      <tbody> 
        <tr> 
            <td>Smith</td> 
            <td>John</td> 
            <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
            <td>$50.00</td> 
            <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>Bach</td> 
            <td>Frank</td> 
            <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
            <td>$50.00</td> 
            <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
        </tr> 
      </tbody>
   </table>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} ); 
}); 
</script>
```

You can also find more info abbout this plugin on [jQuery TableShorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Examples)

Answer (score 0):

here is another simple **sort table using php** code:

make a your-file.php, insert the below code, and upload to your folder. (this example is a very simple table for sorting and processing simple values, using this [sortable.js](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js) script )

```
<html><head>
<script src="sorttable.js"></script>

<style>
tbody tr td {color:green;border-right:1px solid;width:200px;}
</style>
</head><body>

<?php
$First = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$Second = array('1', '2', '3', '4');

if (!empty($_POST['myFirstvalues'])) 
{ $First = explode("\r\n",$_POST['myFirstvalues']); $Second = explode("\r\n",$_POST['mySecondvalues']);}

?>

</br>Hi User. PUT your values</br></br>
<form action="" method="POST">
projectX</br>
<textarea cols="20" rows="20" name="myFirstvalues" style="width:200px;background:url(untitled.PNG);position:relative;top:19px;Float:left;">
<?php foreach($First as $vv) {echo $vv."\r\n";}?>
</textarea>

The due amount</br>
<textarea cols="20" rows="20" name="mySecondvalues" style="width:200px;background:url(untitled.PNG);Float:left;">
<?php foreach($Second as $vv) {echo $vv."\r\n";}?>
</textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<table class="sortable" style="padding:100px 0 0 300px;">
<thead style="background-color:#999999; color:red; font-weight: bold; cursor: default;  position:relative;">
  <tr><th>ProjectX</th><th>Due amount</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
foreach($First as $indx => $value) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$First[$indx].'</td><td>'.$Second[$indx].'</td></tr>';
}
?>
</tbody>
<tfoot><tr><td>TOTAL  = &nbsp;<b>111111111</b></td><td>Still to spend  = &nbsp;<b>5555555</b></td></tr></tfoot></br></br>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like this simple solution from Nick G at [jQuery table sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160277/jquery-table-sort)

```
  $('th').click(function(){
    var table = $(this).parents('table').eq(0)
    var rows = table.find('tr:gt(0)').toArray().sort(comparer($(this).index()))
    this.asc = !this.asc
    if (!this.asc){rows = rows.reverse()}
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){table.append(rows[i])}
})
function comparer(index) {
    return function(a, b) {
        var valA = getCellValue(a, index), valB = getCellValue(b, index)
        return $.isNumeric(valA) && $.isNumeric(valB) ? valA - valB : valA.localeCompare(valB)
    }
}
function getCellValue(row, index){ return $(row).children('td').eq(index).html() }
```