# Sort sql query & ID reset and start in numerical order every time I make a query or sort from <th> tag

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database called **forms1** and a table named **demo**
The fields in the table are **ID**, **Autore**, **Titolo**, **cit**

I wish I had a first line that gives me the ability to sort alphanumeric values ​​that are retrieved by the query, such as 
[image]

How can i modify my code?
This is  ***cerca2.php***:

```
<style>
br {margin-bottom:-10px;}
</style>

<form action="cerca2.php" method="post">
<b>Nome</b>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="Nome">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<b>Numero&nbsp;</b><input type="text" name="Numero">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<b>city&nbsp;</b><input type="text" name="city">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="Submit">
</form>

<style>
tr:nth-of-type(odd) { background-color: AZURE; }
tr:nth-of-type(even) { background-color: CYAN; }
</style>
<style>
tr:hover{background-color<img src="images/smilies/biggrin.gif" border="0" alt="">EEPSKYBLUE;}
</style>

<?php

echo "<table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;border-color: silver;'>";  
echo "<tr style='font-weight: bold;'>";  
echo "<td width='auto' bgcolor=”#7FFFD4&#8243;>&nbsp;<i>ID<i/></td>";  
echo "<td width='auto' >&nbsp;<i>Nome<i/></td>";
echo "<td width='auto' ></td>";
echo "<td ></td>";
echo "</tr>";

define('DB_NAME', 'forms1');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can't use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$Nome = str_replace(' ', '%', $_POST['Nome']);
$Numero = str_replace(' ', '%', $_POST['Numero']); 
$city = str_replace(' ', '%', $_POST['city']); 

$arNome = str_split($Nome);
$arNumero = str_split($Numero);
$arcity = str_split($city);

$Nome='';
foreach ($arNome as $value) 
{
   if ($value=='%') continue;
   $Nome.=$value.'%';

}

$Numero='';
foreach ($arNumero as $value) 
{
   if ($value=='%') continue;
   $Numero.=$value.'%';

}

$city='';
foreach ($arcity as $value) 
{
   if ($value=='%') continue;
   $city.=$value.'%';

}

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM demo WHERE Autore LIKE '%$Nome%' AND Titolo LIKE '%$Numero%' AND cit LIKE '%$city%' ORDER BY Autore") or die(mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width='auto' bgcolor=”#FF0000 &#8243;>" . "&nbsp;". "<b>"  . $row[0] . "&nbsp;". "<b/>". "</td>";
    echo "<td width='auto'>" . "&nbsp;" . $row[1] . "&nbsp;" . "</td>";
    echo "<td width='auto'>". "</td>";
    echo "<td width='auto'>" . "&nbsp;". "<i>" . $row[2] . "<i/>". "&nbsp;" . "</td>";     
    echo "<td width='auto'>" . "&nbsp;". "<i>" . $row[3] . "<i/>". "&nbsp;" . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

I would click on **Nome** and other **th** (except ID) to reorder the values ​​alphanumeric AZ or ZA viceversa when i click. At the moment this is my ***result page*** (look code above) when i call a query:
[image]

I would, too - but I do not know how to do - that the ID value always start from 1 and continue in numerical order according to the number of x values ​​retrieved every time I make a query or sort from *th* tag.
 In my case, instead, is always dependent on the value it represents.
You see it from the picture that the numbers appear in random order.
Here, I do not want this.

Comment: for sorting table columns you may want to have a look at http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: @DavidMichaelHarrison i don't want table sorter i want just click on Nome or other **th** to order A-Z Z-A or numerical/symbols order

Comment: to what end? you said you wanted to click on the th elements in order to "reorder the values alphanumeric"

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. Not so..For sort I mean this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489783/how-to-sort-rows-of-html-table-that-are-called-from-mysql I do not know how to adapt the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code-part:

```
    $i = 0; while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $i++;
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td width='auto' bgcolor=”#FF0000 &#8243;>" . "&nbsp;". "<b>"  . $i . "&nbsp;". "<b/>". "</td>";
        echo "<td width='auto'>" . "&nbsp;" . $row[1] . "&nbsp;" . "</td>";
        echo "<td width='auto'>". "</td>";
        echo "<td width='auto'>" . "&nbsp;". "<i>" . $row[2] . "<i/>". "&nbsp;" . "</td>";     
        echo "<td width='auto'>" . "&nbsp;". "<i>" . $row[3] . "<i/>". "&nbsp;" . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

}
```

Comment: yeah! ID order solve! thank you..but u can help me to order the fields (th) ?

Comment: if u look picture above you can see that **<th> Nome** has not the possibility to sort A-Z or Z-A/numerical-symbols and viceversa. How code can i add to solve this problem? i want able this possibility for all <th> except ID.

Comment: mysql_query("SELECT * FROM demo WHERE Autore LIKE '%$Nome%' AND Titolo LIKE '%$Numero%' AND cit LIKE '%$city%' ORDER BY Autore, Nome ASC")

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. Not so..For sort I mean this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489783/how-to-sort-rows-of-html-table-that-are-called-from-mysql I do not know how to adapt the code