# sort rows of html table - mysql

Tags: php

I have a database called **forms1** and a table named **demo**
The fields in the table are **ID**, **Autore**, **Titolo**, **cit**

I wish I had a first line that gives me the ability to sort alphanumeric values ​​that are retrieved by the query.
**For sort i mean this**:
 [How to sort rows of HTML table that are called from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489783/how-to-sort-rows-of-html-table-that-are-called-from-mysql)

My problem is adapt code for my situation.
This is ***cerca2.php***:

```
<style>
br {margin-bottom:-10px;}
</style>

<form action="cerca2.php" method="post">
<b>Nome</b>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="Nome">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<b>Numero&nbsp;</b><input type="text" name="Numero">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<b>city&nbsp;</b><input type="text" name="city">&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="Submit">
</form>

<style>
tr:nth-of-type(odd) { background-color: AZURE; }
tr:nth-of-type(even) { background-color: CYAN; }
</style>
<style>
tr:hover{background-color:DEEPSKYBLUE;}
</style>

<?php

echo "<table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;border-color: silver;'>";  
echo "<tr style='font-weight: bold;'>";  
echo "<td width='auto' bgcolor=”#7FFFD4″>&nbsp;<i>ID<i/></td>";  
echo "<td width='auto' >&nbsp;<i>Nome<i/></td>";
echo "<td width='auto' ></td>";
echo "<td ></td>";
echo "</tr>";

define('DB_NAME', 'forms1');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$Nome = str_replace(' ', '%', $_POST['Nome']);
$Numero = str_replace(' ', '%', $_POST['Numero']); 
$city = str_replace(' ', '%', $_POST['city']); 

$arNome = str_split($Nome);
$arNumero = str_split($Numero);
$arcity = str_split($city);

$Nome='';
foreach ($arNome as $value) 
{
   if ($value=='%') continue;
   $Nome.=$value.'%';

}

$Numero='';
foreach ($arNumero as $value) 
{
   if ($value=='%') continue;
   $Numero.=$value.'%';

}

$city='';
foreach ($arcity as $value) 
{
   if ($value=='%') continue;
   $city.=$value.'%';

}

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM demo WHERE Autore LIKE '%$Nome%' AND Titolo LIKE '%$Numero%' AND cit LIKE '%$city%' ORDER BY Autore") or die(mysql_error());


$i = 0; while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $i++;
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td width='auto' bgcolor=”#FF0000 &#8243;>" . "&nbsp;". "<b>"  . $i . "&nbsp;". "<b/>". "</td>";
        echo "<td width='auto'>" . "&nbsp;" . $row[1] . "&nbsp;" . "</td>";
        echo "<td width='auto'>". "</td>";
        echo "<td width='auto'>" . "&nbsp;". "<i>" . $row[2] . "<i/>". "&nbsp;" . "</td>";     
        echo "<td width='auto'>" . "&nbsp;". "<i>" . $row[3] . "<i/>". "&nbsp;" . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sort alphanumeric values ​​that are retrieved by the query"? What values? Are you trying to sort results returned by the query? Are you trying to sort within the query itself (you're already sorting by Autore)?

Comment: **Are you trying to sort within the query itself** yes, like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489783/how-to-sort-rows-of-html-table-that-are-called-from-mysql but how must adapt code for my situation?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a Javascript solution [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) would do the job. Handy and easy.

**EDIT**
At the very top add :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tablesorter.com/__jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ $("table").tablesorter(); });
</script>
```

http://pastebin.com/dLJqJQuX

Comment: I try but i don't undestand tablesorter, i don't know how must it include inside my code. Can u help me, please?

Comment: @user143822 Check edition. This would do the job quickly. You may have a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to understand better what i've done.

Comment: This looks like a good JavaScript solution. @user143822 if you want to do this in PHP it's going to involve a lot more work. You'd want to make your table headers clickable links that set a $_GET parameter which you'll use to sort by as per Alexey Sidorov's answer.

Comment: @user143822 I guess that's because you forgot `</table>` Try this full code : http://pastebin.com/dLJqJQuX

Comment: Edition: You need a `<th>` in your table headers instead of `<td>`'s

Comment: i try your code but nothing change look this pic, please http://imageshack.us/a/img209/2514/columnd.png

Answer (score 1):

You should include LIMIT to your sql query, so you have to sort not only data you have already printed, and the hidden.

In your case try to reload page and use $_GET['name_sort'] to change your sql

```
if ($_GET['name_sort'] == 'desc') {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM demo WHERE Autore LIKE '%$Nome%' AND Titolo LIKE '%$Numero%' AND cit LIKE '%$city%' ORDER BY Autore DESC") or die(mysql_error());

} else {

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM demo WHERE Autore LIKE '%$Nome%' AND Titolo LIKE '%$Numero%' AND cit LIKE '%$city%' ORDER BY Autore ASC") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: I try to change but nothing change. Look here the entire code http://pastebin.com/cMLnqELL

Comment: you have to add <a href="/?name_sort=desc"> or <a href="/"> depends on the name_sort param.

Comment: where i have to add your code? Can u post my modified code on Pastebin, please?

Comment: $sortName = '';
$sortNameSql = 'DESC';
if ($_GET['sort_name'] == 'desc') {
  $sortName = 'sort_name=asc';
  $sortNameSql = 'ASC';
}
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM demo WHERE Autore LIKE '%$Nome%' AND Titolo LIKE '%$Numero%' AND cit LIKE '%$city%' ORDER BY Autore " . $sortNameSql . "") or die(mysql_error());

echo '<td width="auto">&nbsp;<a href="/' . $sortName . '"><i>Nome</i></a></td>';

Comment: oh, god :) It`s smth like this))

Comment: i change but something is wrong http://pastebin.com/1iBhpv6C look also the pic http://imageshack.us/a/img197/4599/ordermysql.png

Answer (score 0):

If you want a sortable table, I use the javascript library called "[sortable](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/)" - it's easy to configure and use.

EDIT showing example HTML: This HTML expects the "sortable.js" file to be in the same directory as the HTML file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sortable.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test Table</h1>
    <table id="myTable" class="sortable">
      <tr>
        <th>First Column</th>
        <th>Second Column</th>
        <th>Third Column</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td>10/01/2012</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Goodbye!</td>
        <td>10/04/2011</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Welcome</td>
        <td>22/09/1985</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: read the link in my answer. It explains step-by-step how to implement the solution. If language is a problem, I speak Italian.

Comment: si parlo anche io in italiano, mi daresti un a mano? Ho provato la soluzione sopra la tua, quella di Alexey Sidorov, ma mi cambia nulla

Comment: Allora, devi scaricare prima lo script Javascript, come scritto nel link, poi lo devi includere nella sezione "HEAD" del tuo HTML, in questo modo: `<script type="text/javascript" src="percorso/allo/script/sorttable.js"></script>`. Aggiungi un class CSS `"sortable"` alla tabella, e a quel punto, fa tutto lo script. ENGLISH: You need to download the javascript, as in the link I linked to, then you need to add it to you HTML HEAD section, so: `<script type="javascript/html" src="path/to/script/sorttable.js"></script>`. You need to add a `"sortable"` class to table, and the script does the rest.

Comment: Se vuoi un esempio di come funziona questo script, vai al sito di Fabriano Rugby (google), e guarda la sezione "statistiche". La tabella che vedi usa esattamente questo script "sorttable".

Comment: ho provato ma niente. Ho scritto così: http://pastebin.com/E7Bf4P6K guarda anche l'immagine http://imageshack.us/a/img839/5231/error2we.png

Comment: Purtroppo sono in ufficio, e quei siti sono bloccati dal proxy. Adesso aggiorno la mia risposta con del codice più completo.

Comment: Ho provato ma il problema è che devo implementare il tutto con il php. L'immagine la puoi vedere qui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974176/sort-sql-query-id-reset-and-start-in-numerical-order-every-time-i-make-a-query Praticamente io ho dei form che uso per interrogare il database e quando ho i risultati (nella stesa pagina php) visualizzo le cose in una tabella. Come si fa a implementare il tuo codice e lo script javascript coi comandi echo? Io infatti "stampo" la tabella col php. Il tuo script mi servirebbe per rendere sortable ogni colonna.

Comment: Ma non c'è bisogno di farlo, e quello che ti sto dicendo. Devi fare un echo per produrre l'HTML, no? A quel punto, inserisci tra quegli echo un altro che abbia "<script...></script>" e modifica quello della definizione della tabella in <table id=".." class="..."> e ci pensa lo script Javascript. Non ci sono "commandi" Javascript da scrivere, l'importante è che riesci a fare un echo che includa lo script nell'HEAD dell'HTML.

Comment: pultroppo non so come fare. Io ho tentato, ma è troppo difficile. L'unico modo per capire è il codice completo. Mi riusciresti a fare questo favore? ho inserito questa domanda anche sul forum italiano. Con tablesorter sono andato molto vicino, ma ci sono problemi di formattazione. Guarda qui, ti prego http://forum.html.it/forum/showthread.php?s=&threadid=1525094