# Order rows by clicking column name

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have to order the showed list by clicking on the column-name. I have started with inspiration from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489783/how-to-sort-rows-of-html-table-that-are-called-from-mysql), but don't know how to continue with it.

This is my code:

```html
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT rid, pid, firstname, lastname, email FROM temp_members_db WHERE pid='$pid1' ");

echo "<br><table><tr class='tabletop'><th><a href='mypage.php?sort=type'>Namn</a></th><th><a href='mypage.php?sort=type'>E-mail</a></th><th><a href='mypage.php?sort=type'>Resultat</a></th><th>Ta bort kandidat</th></tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

echo "<tr><td><strong>
<form action='respondent2.php' method='GET'>
 <input type='hidden' name='rid' value='".$row['rid']."'>
 <input type='hidden' name='firstname' value='".$row['firstname']."'> 
<input type='submit' class='resname' name='submit' value='".$row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname']."'>
 </form>
 </strong></td> 
 <td>".$row['email']."</td> 
 <td><strong><span style=\"color: $color\">".$result00."</span>%</strong></td>   
 <form action='deleterespondent2.php' method='post'>
 <input type='hidden' name='rid' value='".$row['rid']."'> 
<td> <input type='submit' class='mydel' value='Radera' onclick=\"return confirm('Show me!')\">
 </form>
</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";?>
```

As you see I have started by writing `<a href="mypage.php?sort=type">` at every column name, without knowing what to write exactly instead of "type". What I want is to be able to click on the column header and sort the rows below based on the chosen column, for example Name. Then, of course, I want the belonging rows to follow each other, not only the chosen column to change order.

Comment: Has your question been answered?

Comment: @Eugene Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Oh. Did you try my code? And it didn't work? Any error messages? Maybe post your database and I can code you a live example. This is pretty simple stuff, if you still are having problems, let's get you sorted!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
if ($_GET['sort'] == 'namn')
{
    $order = " ORDER BY lastname";
}
elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'email')
{
    $order = " ORDER BY email";
}

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT rid, pid, firstname, lastname, email FROM temp_members_db WHERE pid='$pid1' ".$order);

echo "<br><table><tr class='tabletop'><th><a href='mypage.php?sort=namn'>Namn</a></th><th><a href='mypage.php?sort=email'>E-mail</a></th><th>Resultat</th><th>Ta bort kandidat</th></tr>";
```

Comment: There is no point to defend ORDER BY clause from SQL injection, if WHERE is still wide open :)

Answer (score 0):

**Please use parameterized queries**:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db', port);
if($result = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT rid, pid, firstname, lastname, email FROM temp_members_db WHERE pid=?")) {
    $result -> bind_param("i", $pid1); // Assuming pid1 is an integer
    $result -> execute();
    $result -> store_result();
    $result -> bind_result($pid);
    while($result -> fetch()) {
      echo $pid; // etc etc
    }  
}
```

Reading for you:

1. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
2. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet

Similar to Drew's suggestion:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db', port);
$order_string = ""
// Assuming PHP >= 5.4, otherwise use array()
$sort_keywords = [
    "namn" => "lastname",
    "email" => "email",
];
if(isset($_GET['sort']) && array_key_exists($_GET['sort'], $sort_keywords)) {
    $order_string = " ORDER BY ".$sort_keywords[$_GET['sort']];
}
// Assume <head>, <body> etc etc here.
echo "<br><table><tr class='tabletop'><th><a href='mypage.php?sort=namn'>Namn</a></th><th><a href='mypage.php?sort=email'>E-mail</a></th><th>Resultat</th><th>Ta bort kandidat</th></tr>";

if($result = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT rid, pid, firstname, lastname, email FROM temp_members_db WHERE pid=?".$order_string)) {
    $result -> bind_param("i", $pid1); // Assuming pid1 is an integer
    $result -> execute();
    $result -> store_result();
    $result -> bind_result($rid, $pid, $firstname, $lastname, $email);
    while($result -> fetch()) {
        // $color? $result00?
        echo "<tr><td><strong>
        <form action='respondent2.php' method='GET'>
         <input type='hidden' name='rid' value='".$rid."'>
         <input type='hidden' name='firstname' value='".$firstname."'> 
        <input type='submit' class='resname' name='submit' value='".$firstname." ".$lastname."'>
         </form>
         </strong></td> 
         <td>".$email."</td> 
         <td><strong><span style=\"color: $color\">".$result00."</span>%</strong></td>   
         <form action='deleterespondent2.php' method='post'>
         <input type='hidden' name='rid' value='".$rid."'> 
        <td> <input type='submit' class='mydel' value='Radera' onclick=\"return confirm('Show me!')\">
         </form>
        </td></tr>";
    }  
}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Or (exactly the same):

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db', port);
$order_string = ""
// Assuming PHP >= 5.4, otherwise use array()
$sort_keywords = [
    "namn" => "lastname",
    "email" => "email",
];
if(isset($_GET['sort']) && array_key_exists($_GET['sort'], $sort_keywords)) {
    $order_string = " ORDER BY ".$sort_keywords[$_GET['sort']];
}
// Assume <head>, <body> etc etc here.
?>
<br><table><tr class='tabletop'><th><a href='mypage.php?sort=namn'>Namn</a></th><th><a href='mypage.php?sort=email'>E-mail</a></th><th>Resultat</th><th>Ta bort kandidat</th></tr>
<?php
if($result = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT rid, pid, firstname, lastname, email FROM temp_members_db WHERE pid=?".$order_string)) {
    $result -> bind_param("i", $pid1); // Assuming pid1 is an integer
    $result -> execute();
    $result -> store_result();
    $result -> bind_result($rid, $pid, $firstname, $lastname, $email);
    while($result -> fetch()) {
        // $color? $result00?
        ?>
        <tr><td><strong>
        <form action='respondent2.php' method='GET'>
         <input type='hidden' name='rid' value='<?php echo $rid; ?>'>
         <input type='hidden' name='firstname' value='<?php echo $firstname; ?>'> 
        <input type='submit' class='resname' name='submit' value='<?php echo $firstname; ?> <?php echo $lastname; ?>'>
         </form>
         </strong></td> 
         <td><?php echo $email; ?></td> 
         <td><strong><span style="color: <?php echo $color; ?>"><?php echo $result00; ?></span>%</strong></td>   
         <form action='deleterespondent2.php' method='post'>
         <input type='hidden' name='rid' value='<?php echo $rid; ?>'> 
        <td> <input type='submit' class='mydel' value='Radera' onclick="return confirm('Show me!')">
         </form>
        </td></tr>
    <?php
    }  
}
?>
</table>
```

Also, probably best to define the sort array in the database and have them `echo`ed as an attribute in the html table row header. I would personally just sort on the client side, which is actually sometimes quicker (`ORDER BY` can be slow), however, I am unaware of your intentions.

Have fun with the edits ;)