# How to remove HTML code in print preview?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

[How to sort rows of HTML table that are called from MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489783/how-to-sort-rows-of-html-table-that-are-called-from-mysql)

I used the above sorting method to sort my table data. But when I go for printing the table, the column headers are supported with `?orderBy=colname`. I do not want this to be printed. How should I remove it?

This is how column headers look like on [Print Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KB88y.png).

Comment: Can you post your HTML and/or PHP?

Comment: Is this extraneous text not present on the page and only shows up in the print preview? Without code there is little we can do.