# Sort table and color column

Tags: php, mysql

I made my table sortable with the help of this link: 
[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489783/how-to-sort-rows-of-html-table-that-are-called-from-mysql)

Is there any way to make the targeted column a different color following the accepted answer? So you can see, which column is sorted by?

UPDATE UPDATE

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM s5_players";    
if ($_GET['sort'] == 'matches')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY matches";
}
elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'goals')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY goals";
}
elseif ($_GET['sort'] == 'assists')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY assists";
}
elseif($_GET['sort'] == 'cards')
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY cards";
}
else
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY goals";
}
$>
```

and:

```
<td>Name:</td>
<td><a href="mypage.php?sort=matches">Matches:</td>
<td><a href="mypage.php?sort=goals">Goals:</a></td>
<td><a href="mypage.php?sort=assists">Assists:</a></td>
<td><a href="mypage.php?sort=cards">Cards:</a></td>
```

And further down like this:

```
$number = 1;
foreach($results as $row){
echo '
<tr class="statistikker">
<td style="background: #666; text-align: center; color: white; font-weight: bold;">'.$number.'</td>
<td style="padding-left: 5px">'.$row->name.'</td>
<td class="center">'.$row->matches.'</td>
<td class="center">'.$row->goal.'</td>
<td class="center">'.$row->assist.'</td>
<td class="center">'.$row->cards.'</td>
</tr>';
$number++;
};
```

Comment: give the td some `style="color:red;"` if `$_GET['sort'] == 'type'`

Comment: Please provide a relevant sample of your code so we can work from there

Comment: @PierreC. just added my code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is not optimized but does what you want to achieve.

```
$number = 1;

foreach($results as $row){
    echo '
        <tr class="statistikker">
            <td style="background: #666; text-align: center; color: white; font-weight: bold;">'.$number.'</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 5px">'.$row->name.'</td>
            <td class="center '.($_GET['sort'] == 'matches' ? 'selected' : '').'">'.$row->matches.'</td>
            <td class="center '.((!isset($_GET['sort']) || $_GET['sort'] == 'goal' ? 'selected' : '').'">'.$row->goal.'</td>
            <td class="center '.($_GET['sort'] == 'assist' ? 'selected' : '').'">'.$row->assist.'</td>
            <td class="center '.($_GET['sort'] == 'cards' ? 'selected' : '').'">'.$row->cards.'</td>
        </tr>';
    $number++;
};
```

**Update:** I added the `!isset($_GET['sort'])` on the *goal* `td` elements to reflect the OP comment below stating *goal* was the standard sort parameter.

It adds the class `selected` to the relevant `td` elements. You can then create a CSS rule for this `selected` class that changes the `background-color` property like so:

```
.selected {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you! I made it sort by goals as standard when the page is loaded. Is there a way I can make that one selected as soon as the page is loaded?

Comment: @DanielJensen I updated the answer to do just that. I hope it works fine :)